# How to send Subscribers Key in the Cloud Page Url to Fetch / Auto Populate the Subscriber's data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, profile, cloudpage, subscriber-key

**My requirement** : I want a custom profile center where in the user if click on the footer link it sends him to a page with his auto populated attribute like First Name  , Last Name and the publications he is subscribed to.

**My Try** :I have created a cloud page which I want to use as a custom profile center/Subscribe / Unsubscribe page. All I want is how can I send the Subscriber's key in the cloud page Url , once the subscriber hits the subscribe/update profile button he is landed to a cloud page with is auto - populated attributes like : First Name , Last Name.Publications subscribed to.

Below code : One is where I am sending the hard coded attributes of user to subscribe .

second : Code to retrieve the subscriber datq using his hard coded Subscriber's key.

**Input From 1** :

```
</script>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="py-5 text-center">
            <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="https://www.usac.org/_res/images/logo-2016.png" alt="" style="  float:left;">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1" style="color: #31708f;
               background-color: #d9edf7;border-color: #bce8f1;">
               <form action="http://cl.s10.exct.net/subscribe.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
                  <input type="hidden" name="thx" value="https://www.thebalancecareers.com/thmb/LhHWsTiDL7S0Ik2eh72h4ljg5gw=/3865x2576/filters:fill(auto,1)/thank-you-185078737-58adfa013df78c345b0837e7.jpg"> 
                  <input type="hidden" name="err" value="https://support.nmi.com/hc/article_attachments/115002846451/mceclip1.png"> 
                  <input type="hidden" name="SubAction" value="sub_add_update"> 
                  <input type="hidden" name="MID" value="100024807">
              <div class="mb-3">
                 <h1> Manage Subscriptions</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                 <label>First Name <span class="text-muted">*</span></label>
                 <input id="frstName" name="First Name" class="form-control">
                 <br>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                 <label>Last Name<span class="text-muted">*</span></label>
                 <input id="lstname" type="text" class="form-control" name="Last Name">
                 <br>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                 <label>Email<span class="text-muted">*</span></label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email Address">
                 <br>
              </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
                 <label>Title</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Title">
                 <br>
              </div>

   <div class="mb-3">
                 <label>Role within your organization as it pertains to universal service</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Role within your organization as it pertains to universal service">
                 <br>
              </div>
  <!--<div class="mb-3">
                 <label>Phone Number</label>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Phone Number">
                 <br/>
              </div> -
```

**Second Code :**

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");  
  // url value suscribe key  
   var sub = Subscriber.Init('5');
  var att = sub.Attributes.Retrieve();
  var test = '';
 for(var k in att) {
   //test += att[k].Name + '<br/> \n';
    test += att[k].Value + '<br/> \n';
}
</script>
```

**How can i get subscribers data dynamically. in the cloud pages.**

Comment: Is this unsubscribe page hosted in a cloudpage?

Comment: There are countless examples here on SFSE on how to: 1 - pass subscriberkey in e.g. CloudpagesUrl, and 2 - populate form from a data extension/list using AmpScript.

Comment: @Gortonington :  Yes we are hoting it on the cloud page. As standard one is not required .

Comment: You need to utilize ampscript to pull directly from a Data extension.  Like Luke said, there’s tons of examples.  Reference the sf documentation on cloudpagesurl function within email and ampscript blocks on landing page to call AttributeValue. Ampscript is proprietary server side language.